# Authentication Statistics are the same for all apps

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, api-v2, statistics

I know the stats are new, I'm not sure if they are still in development. But they are identical for the 3 apps I have registered, given that the app's id is in the URL of the stats page, I guess the should be different for each app?

Answer (score 1):

This will be fixed in the next build, we were returning total API stats instead of per-app stats.  Silly oversight.